# Embedding a custom video in a XCUITest

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xctest, xcuitest

I'm writing a test that is supposed to test uploading a video file, using XCUITest in XCode 12. The test is supposed to be self-contained so I'm not certain how to exactly do this.

Typically I want the flow to work like this:

1. App builds
2. File is copied from the code folder (I've moved the video to be in the code) into the simulator
3. Tests run

However step 2 is giving me a ton of problems. I'm trying using this in a build phase:

`xcrun simctl addmedia booted ~/code/resources/Video.mov`

Bur it's currently giving a completely unspecified error. I'm not sure if this is because I'm trying to do it before the simulator is "booted" or if something else is going on. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The correct way to do this was to just use a `.` instead of `~` and then realize that:

`.` puts you at the project level (.xcproj)